# how to use struct in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

I am of late working on gcc compiler. whenevr i m compiling my code, m encountering problem with declaration of structure. How to tackle this problem. Do i need to write the syntax  differently in gcc?. if yes, how? please suggest something.

Comment: Please show us the code that is causing problem on gcc.

Comment: I think that what is really causing a problem is your code not `struct` itself.

Comment: Also show us the error messages generated by the compiler.

Comment: As others have said, show the code and the error messages. Don't just show the structure declaration, also show the code before it. There is a good chance that the problem is not with the structure declaration but with the code before it. For example, maybe you have a header file that uses a non-portable construct shortly before the structure declaration, or maybe you've forgotten to include a header file and an identifier that should be a type name is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reasonably sure gcc conforms to C standards, for a more succinct explanation than one found in the standard, please, turn to pages 148-150 of [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/).

So something simple like this linked list element:

```
struct foo 
{
  int a;
  float b;
  char *s;
  struct foo *next;
} my_struct;
```

should work.

If your needs are more complex.. then you should post your non-working example.

EDIT: If you don't have access to CAR then this will suffice for now: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html (obviously not C99)